# не могу указать конструкторы для элементов массива из CircleShape

Tags: c++, sfml

см. исходник. сделал массив из указателей на CircleShape, хочу в цикле конструктор сделать для каждого элемента и инициализировать, а не выходит.
помогите, пожалуйста

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()

{

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(200, 200), "SFMLworks");
    CircleShape *shapeq[10];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    
        shapeq[i]->//!!!!!!!!вот тут хочу указать конструктор, а не выходит. !!!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CircleShape *shapeq[10];
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    shapeq[i] = new CircleShape(/*Ваши параметры для конструктора*/)
```

Comment: точняк. вот я валенок )))